# cannot connect to suse linux server remotely using ssh

Tags: ssh, suse

i have SuSE10 SP2 installed.
I have started the ssh daemon and iam able to login locally on the server
but when i try to connect remotely using putty i get connection refused error.
I have disabled the firewall on suse. and also i am able to telnet remotely some how ssh is denied.

did i miss some ssh configuration?

please help.

kind Regards
jc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need more information, for example, the content of sshd_config (eg., /etc/ssh/sshd_config) file, and the state of the server IP tables ("iptables -L" ran as root or through sudo).

A couple of things that worked for me in the past:

- Do you have a router between your computer and the server? Is it blocking port 22? Is your ISP blocking port 22?
- Try another port by changing the Port directive in your sshd config file and restarting your sshd daemon:

  Port 2222
- Are you using TCP wrappers (e.g., what do you see in /etc/hosts.allow)? This is independent of the firewall.
- As a previous user mentioned, are you trying to log as root (not recommended, but then, you need "PermitRootLogin yes")?

Comment: I had this problem recently and I just needed to forward port 22 in the router, although if I did it again I would use a non-standard port (automated attacks started within 8 hours). @JHC Make sure root isn't allowed to ssh, or even better allow only one specific account ssh access.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the exact same problem. According to `tcpdump` the packets were arriving at the host on port 22. Put `sshd` server into debug mode, there were no requests being received.

Turned out to be the firewall that was blocking it. Used [YaST](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal:YaST) to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If you try log in into "root" account you may need change "PermitRootLogin" option to yes (in sshd_config). Try also run ssh with debug (e.g. ssh -vvv ...) maybe there you will find some hints. Did you check system logs?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall configuration.  Your server may be blocking inbound connection attempts.

Specifically, check the configuration of iptables.  Be sure it's permitting TCP connections on port 22.